# Ping from one subnet to another only responds on the first packet

Tags: networking, router, switch, subnet

We have two subnets in the office: `xxx.xxx.1.0/24` for our workstations and server, and `xxx.xxx.100.0/24` for our CNC machines. The `xxx.xxx.1.0/24` network uses an HP 2920-48g switch, and the `xxx.xxx.100.0/24` network uses a bintec R232b router.

Yesterday I was able to ping from `xxx.xxx.100.101` to anyone on `xxx.xxx.1.0/24`. I successfully mapped a network drive on `xxx.xxx.100.101` pointing to our server.

Today, I am unable to access the network drive. When I ping from `xxx.xxx.100.101` to anyone on `xxx.xxx.1.0/24`, the first packet goes through and subsequent packets fail:

```
>ping xxx.xxx.1.221

Pinging xxx.xxx.1.221 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for xxx.xxx.1.221:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 1, Lost = 3 (75% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

The `tracert` hits the bintec router and then times out:

```
>tracert xxx.xxx.1.221

Tracing route to xxx.xxx.1.221 over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  xxx.xxx.100.200
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.


Trace complete.
```

What could have caused this to happen overnight? There were no intentional configuration or hardware changes made. The bintec router is shut off overnight.

Here are the configuration screens for the bintec router:

[image: bintec interfaces]

[image: bintec routing]

Comment: The router may have had unsaved configuration changes, and when it was shut down and came back up, it reverted to a saved, older, non-working configuration.

Comment: Of course, the bintec router reverted back to the last saved configuration. I was able to get it working by setting the en5-0 interface to a static IP of `xxx.xxx.1.15`, which was the IP specified by the HP switch vendor.